# HTML/CSS & Bootstrap Columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a basic "placeholder" page for a company that my sister is creating, I've done the codecademy HTML/CSS Beginner Course so I have a little bit of knowledge on the way it should work but for some reason I am unable to make the bootstrap columns sit next to each other on the page, for some reason they want to stack on top of each other.. I'm using CoffeeCup HTML Editor(dunno if that makes any difference)

Here's my code
HTML:

```
  <div class="header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
               <h1>NRTHRNTWNS</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
```

and all my CSS has in it is :

```
@font-face {
font-family: Northern;
src: url(nrthrntwnsskinnier-Regular.otf);
 }

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Northern, serif;
 }

 /* Header */

div h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
}
div a {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: First, a sanity check: is the browser/preview window/etc that you are viewing this page on wide enough for them to be side by side? By default bootstrap stacks elements at screen sizes lower than `991px`.

Comment: Also, if you could post any attempts that you tried to fix the problem, that would greatly aid in solving the problem you're having.

Comment: Should be plenty wide, using default resolution on HD monitors. I've tried many different things to no avail. I pulled some code directly out of my codecademy assignments and they seem to work just fine using the exact same method.

Comment: Did you added the <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/your/bootstrap.css" /> into your html file?

Comment: have you added the link to bootstrap css and js in the page head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is you didn't include bootstrap in the top of your page so col-md-6 won't work

put this in the head

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: Jeez I'm dumb.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood the problem, this solution can help u:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <h1>col-1</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
               <h1>NRTHRNTWNS</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Northern;
src: url(nrthrntwnsskinnier-Regular.otf);
 }

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Northern, serif;
 }

 /* Header */

div h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
}
div a {
  color: black;
}
```

You can see solution in JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skriming/wvahufh8/

Comment: I tried this in my html editor and then did a "test with default browser(chrome)" and I still have them stacking on top of each other, but it works in fiddle just fine?